# How to handle empty array when combining map and filter in react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, filter

I'm having a array that contains NFT details, I'm filtering the NFT with contract address and then map it to the individual component.

Everything is working fine, But the main problem is when there is no nft matches then the filter function returns empty array,  I want to display something else like NO NFT found for this contract address, Instead of displaying none.

```
          <div className="flex justify-center">
            {nft?.ownedNfts
              ?.filter((nfts: { contract: { address: string } }) => {
                if (nftIndex == 0) {
                  return (
                    nfts?.contract?.address ==
                    Data.nftContractAddress
                  );
                } else {
                  return (
                    nfts?.contract?.address !=
                    Data.nftContractAddress
                  );
                }
              })
              .map(
                (nfts: {
                  title: string;
                  tokenId: {};
                }) => (
                  <NFTCards
                    key={nfts.id?.tokenId}
                    Name={nfts.title}
                  />
                )
              )}
          </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest handling the filter operation before in your component this way you could have `filteredNfts` and a conditional in your JSX.

```
  <div>
    { filteredNfts ? filteredNfts.map(...) : <p>No nft found</p>}
  </div>
```